# Count all records that does not exist to other table - SQL Query

Tags: mysql

I have two(2) tables and I'm trying to count all records from Table1 and Table1_delta were pagename from Table1_delta is not yet listed into Table1. Incase pagename from Table1_delta is listed to Table1, status must be 1 so that it will be included in count result.

Sample table structure:

**Table1**

```
+-----------+--------+
| pagename  | status |
+-----------+--------+
| pagename1 |   2    |
| pagename2 |   1    |
+-----------+--------+
```

**Table1_delta**

```
+-----------+
| pagename  |
+-----------+
| pagename1 |
| pagename2 |
| pagename3 |
| pagename4 |
+-----------+
```

The table sample should return **"3"**.

pagename3 and pagename4 is not listed in Table1(that returns 2) and pagename2 from Table1 has an status = 1(that returns 1). In total there are **3 pagenames** from Table1_delta that are not listed in Table1 and record from Table1 where status = 1. I'm wondering on how will be the query of this? I'm using MySQL v5.6.17. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative solution using joins:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Table1_delta t1 LEFT JOIN Table1 t2
ON t1.pagename = t2.pagename
WHERE t2.status IS NULL OR t2.status = 1
```

Here is what the temporary table from the above query looks like:

```
+-----------+--------+
| pagename  | status |
+-----------+--------+
| pagename1 |  2     |    # this row is NOT counted
| pagename2 |  1     |    # +1 this row has status = 1 and is counted
| pagename3 |  null  |    # +1 this row has status = null and is counted
| pagename4 |  null  |    # +1 this row is also null and is counted
+-----------+--------+
```

Check out the link below for a running demo.

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/106d4/1)**

Comment: Good catch...I caught it about 1 minute before you did :-)

Comment: Hi there. Can you explain how this one works sir? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @KenCar this query matches `Table1_delta` to `Table1` and then counts the number of rows which either do _not_ have a `status` _or_ have a `status` of 1.  The result is `3` for the sample data you gave in your OP.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1_Delta
WHERE pagename NOT IN 
  (SELECT pagename FROM Table1 WHERE status = 1)
```

#### Update

As requested  in the comments, here's what this query does:

First, the subquery: `SELECT pagename FROM Table1 WHERE status = 1`, retrieves the `pagename` field from those `Table1` records where status is 1.

So in the example case, it'll return a single row, containing `pagename2`.

Then the main query counts all the records in `Table1_Delta` (`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1_Delta`) whose `Pagename` does **not** contain (`WHERE Pagename NOT IN (<subquery>)`) those values returned from the subquery.

So this would match 3 entries (`pagename1`, `pagename3`, `pagename4`), and that's the count you get

Historically, using sub-queries is considered slower than using joins, but frankly, RDBMS's have come a long way optimizing queries, and for simple cases like this, it would be "probably" (I haven't measured) faster. It actually depends on the *real* case and DB... but the SQL code is much more self-explanatory than joins IMO. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Hi there. Can you explain how this one works sir? Thanks.

Comment: It counts all the records in `Table1_delta` where `Pagename` is **not** in the subquery. The subquery selects all `Pagename` fields from `Table1` where status is 1. You can see a fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/106d4/2/0 . Let me edit the question with some explanation

Comment: @KenCar I added an explanation, let me know if it's enough

Answer (score 0):

Try using joins

```
Select count(Table1_delta.pagename) from Table1_delta 
INNER JOIN Table1 ON 
    Table1_delta.pagename != Table1 .pagename 
    AND Table1.status != 1
```

Comment: This is wrong on all clauses. It'll always return an equivalent amount of records of those in `Table1_Delta`, no matter what

Comment: Still wrong after the edit... in the example case, it'll return 4, not 3 :-)

Comment: Uh... no. I don't think `GROUP tablename` is even correct syntax, but even if you mean `GROUP BY Table1_delta.pagename` it'd only make 4 groups of count 1. The `LEFT JOIN` clauses are just wrong. Check @TimBiegeleisen 's answer, which is the correct way to do it with joins